# size of table in sql alchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to find the size of my tables. I have this query for MySQL which works but I have no idea how to query information_schema in sqlalchemy without raw SQL. Any ideas ?

```sql
SELECT (data_length+index_length)/power(1024,3) tablesize_gb
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='db1' and table_name='table1';
```

Comment: Why would it require raw SQL injection?

Comment: @IljaEverilä sorry i wasn't clear, just without raw SQL. Like do you know how to format the above query using the sql alchemy syntax.